# Kernel Panic while compiling PHP

Tags: php, fedora, kernel-panic

The server threw a 'kernel: Oops: 0000 [1] SMP' while compiling PHP 5.4.9.

It crashed when I try it again just to make sure that it was the culprit.

Other than that, the server works fine.

Its kinda old and running on a very old operating system: 2.6.23.17-88.fc7

Before the server became unresponsive, I checked the dmesg log for errors but there was none.

Am I missing any logs? Any tips on how I can troubleshoot this kernel panic?

I would like to add that I also compiled Nginx but that went fine.

Comment: Why are you compiling php instead of installing an RPM?

Comment: Replace the defective hardware.

Comment: @EEAA I thought of compiling because the latest version from the repository was 5.2.6.

Comment: And that's because you're running an OS that you should have decommissioned four years ago. Apparently on some hardware that's past its useful life, too. Scrap the whole thing and start over.

Answer (score 6):

Kernel panic on relatively high load of server often indicates hardware problems. Check your processor temperature, run memory test, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile it not under the root user (anyway better way is to install it via RPM).

Comment: The user you compile under should have no effect on this problem (though generally it's better to use the vendor-supplied packages if at all possible).